# python fancy indexing with a boolean masked array

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, masked-array

I have a numpy masked array of data:

```
data = masked_array(data = [7 -- 7 1 8 -- 1 1 -- -- 3 -- -- 3 --],
                    mask = [False True False False False True False False True True False True True False True])
```

I have a flag of a specific type of data, which is a boolean masked array:

```
flag = masked_array(data = [True False False True -- -- -- False -- True -- -- -- -- True],
                    mask = [False False False False True True True False True False True True True True False])
```

I want to do something like `data[flag]` and get the following output:

```
output_wanted = [7 1 -- --]
```

which corresponds to the data elements where the flag is True. Instead I get this:

```
output_real = [7 -- 7 1 8 -- 1 1 -- -- 3 -- -- 3 --]
```

I did not copied the masks of the outputs for better clarity.

I dont mind having an output with the size of the flag as long as it selects the data I want (the one corresponding to the True values of the flag). But I cannot figure out why it gives theses values in the real output !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I reconstruct your arrays with:

```
In [28]: d=np.ma.masked_equal([7,0,7,1,8,0,1,1,0,0,3,0,0,3,0],0)

In [29]: f=np.ma.MaskedArray([True,False,False,True, False,False,False,False,True,True,True,True,True,True,True],[False, False, False, False, True, True, True, False, True, False, True, True, True, True, False])

In [30]: d
Out[30]: 
masked_array(data = [7 -- 7 1 8 -- 1 1 -- -- 3 -- -- 3 --],
             mask = [False  True False False False  True False False  True  True False  True
  True False  True],
       fill_value = 0)

In [31]: f
Out[31]: 
masked_array(data = [True False False True -- -- -- False -- True -- -- -- -- True],
             mask = [False False False False  True  True  True False  True False  True  True
  True  True False],
       fill_value = True)
```

The masked displays match, but I'm guessing at what the masked values are.

```
In [32]: d[f]
Out[32]: 
masked_array(data = [7 1 -- -- 3 -- -- 3 --],
             mask = [False False  True  True False  True  True False  True],
       fill_value = 0)

In [33]: d[f.data]
Out[33]: 
masked_array(data = [7 1 -- -- 3 -- -- 3 --],
             mask = [False False  True  True False  True  True False  True],
       fill_value = 0)
```

Indexing the `f` is the same as indexing with its `data` attribute.  Its mask does nothing.  Evidently my masked values are different from yours.

But if I index with a `filled` array, I get the desired array:

```
In [34]: d[f.filled(False)]
Out[34]: 
masked_array(data = [7 1 -- --],
             mask = [False False  True  True],
       fill_value = 0)
```

`filled` is used a lot in `np.ma` code, with differing fill values depending on the `np` operation (e.g. 0 for sum v 1 for product).  Masked arrays don't usually iterate over their values skipping the masked ones; instead they convert the masked ones to innocuous values, and use regular numpy operations.  The other strategy is to remove the masked values with `compressed`.

`indices = np.where(flag.filled(False))` is mentioned in another answer, but plain boolean form works just as well.

A masked array has a `data` and `mask` attribute.  Masking does not change the `data` values directly. That task is left to methods like `filled`.

Comment: It strikes me as a bug that indexing with a masked array is even allowed, given that doing so seems to break the semantic of the masked array that the fill_value shouldn't matter. I'd expect there to be a `if isinstance(boolmask, MaskedArray) and getmask(boolmask) is not False: raise ValueError` or something

Comment: Indexing is implemented by passing a `indx` tuple to a `d.__getitem__` method.  If `d` is a masked array, it delegates the task to `d.data[indx]` and `d.mask[indx]`.  That `indx` tuple could have slices, scalars, lists, arrays, etc.  Blocking masked arrays from such a tuple will require a lot of extra logic - and not only for masked array indexing.  `np.arange(15)[f]`?

Answer (score 2):

What about something like:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.ma import masked_array

data = masked_array(data = [7,     0,     7,     1,     8,     0,    1,     1,     0,    0,     3,     0,    0,    3,     0],
                    mask = [False, True,  False, False, False, True, False, False, True, True,  False, True, True, False, True])
flag = masked_array(data = [True,  False, False, True,  0,     0,    0,     False, 0,    True,  0,     0,    0,    0,     True],
                    mask = [False, False, False, False, True,  True, True,  False, True, False, True,  True, True, True,  False])

print(repr(data))
print(repr(flag))

indices = np.where(flag & ~flag.mask)
print(data[indices])
```

Note, you may get into trouble if the masked values in `flag` can't be compared with `&`, but it doesn't look like that's the case for you.

Output:

```
masked_array(data = [7 -- 7 1 8 -- 1 1 -- -- 3 -- -- 3 --],
             mask = [False  True False False False  True False False  True  True False  True  True False  True],
       fill_value = 999999)

masked_array(data = [1 0 0 1 -- -- -- 0 -- 1 -- -- -- -- 1],
             mask = [False False False False  True  True  True False  True False  True  True  True  True False],
       fill_value = 999999)

[7 1 -- --]
```

Edit:

An alternative way of getting the indices might also be:

```
indices = np.where(flag.filled(False))
```

---

#### Update (Edit 2):

Beware of the subtleties of indexing arrays using arrays.

Consider the following code:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
mask = np.array([True, False, True, False, True])

res  = data[mask]
print(res)
```

As you might (or might not) expect, here, the mask serves as a "filter", filtering out the elements of data where the corresponding location in the mask is False.  Because of the values I choose for the `data` and `mask`, the effect is that the indexing serves to filter out the even `data` values leaving only the odd ones.

The output here is: `[1 3 5]`.

Now, consider the ***very** similar* code:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
mask = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1])

res  = data[mask]
print(res)
```

Here, the only thing changed is datatype of the mask elements, their boolean value is the same.  Let's call the first mask (comprised of `True`/`False` values) `mask1` and the second mask (comprised of `1`/`0` values) `mask2`.

You can inspect the datatype of arrays through the `dtype` attribute (e.g. `print(mask.dtype)`).  `mask1` has a dtype of `bool`, while `mask2` has a dtype of `int32`.

**Here, however, the output is different:** `[2 1 2 1 2]`.

What's going on here?

In fact, indexing behaves differently depending on the datatype of the array used to index.  As mentioned, when the datatype of the "mask" is boolean, it serves a filtering function.  But when the datatype of the "mask" is integral, it serves a "selection" function, using the elements of the index as indices of the original array.

So, in the second example, since `data[1] = 2` and `data[0] = 1`, the result of `data[mask2]` is an array of length 5, not 3 (in the boolean case).

Put another way, given the following code:

```
res = data[mask]
```

If `mask.dtype == int`, the length of res will be equal to the length of mask.

If `mask.dtype == bool`, the length of res will be equal to the number of `True` values in mask.

Quite a difference.

Lastly, you can coerce an array of one datatype to another using the `astype` method.

Demonstration snippet:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

# Create a boolean mask
mask1 = np.array([True, False, True, False, True])

# Create an integer "mask", using the same logical values 
mask2 = np.array([1,0,1,0,1])

# Coerce mask2 into a boolean mask
mask3 = mask2.astype(bool)

print(data)         # [1 2 3 4 5]
print("-" * 80)
print(mask1)        # [True  False  True  False  True]
print(mask1.dtype)  # bool
print(data[mask1])  # [1 3 5]
print("-" * 80)
print(mask2)        # [1 0 1 0 1]
print(mask2.dtype)  # int32
print(data[mask2])  # [2 1 2 1 2]
print("-" * 80)
print(mask3)        # [True  False  True  False  True]
print(mask3.dtype)  # bool
print(data[mask3])  # [1 3 5]
```

Comment: Yes that works thanks. But do you know how python deals with the indexing when given a boolean masked array ? I dont understand the output

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how indexing with masked arrays works.

In fact, python does not deal with this kind of indexing.

When doing something like `data[flag]` with `flag` a boolean masked array, python takes the underlying data of `flag`. In other words, it takes the values of the masked values before they were masked.

So beware: if the masked values are not explicitly filled with their `fill_value`, the indexing may look random.

Example:

```
>>> arr = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> flag = np.ma.masked_array([True, False, False, True, True],
                              [False, True, False, False, True])

>>> arr[flag])
array([0, 3, 4])
```

One way to do it is like jedwards answer.

But I think masked arrays should be avoided to flag data, it does not bring sufficient insight.

In case of a flag array that is used to access a certain type of data, masked values should be set to `False`. For ex if you want to interpolate the data that are not flagged.

If the flag array is used to mask a certain type of data masked values should be set to True.

Comment: `data[flag[~flag.mask]]` won't work as you expect for two reasons.  The first is that `flag[~flag.mask]` returns an integer array, not boolean as you would need (see update 2 to my post).  The second is that the length of the array, even if coerced to boolean, will be too small, and filter incorrect elements.  In my version of numpy, attempting this shows a `VisibileDeprecationWarning` informing me of the length difference.

Comment: Yep I noticed the length problem when testing. But why does `flag[~flag.mask]` return an int array ??